# Converting .live() to .on() with complex selector

Tags: jquery

How can this be converted from .live() to .on()?

```
$('[id^=generic1_id_]', '[id^=generic2_id_]').live('click', function(){
```

To convert to .on(), I could create two working examples seen below, but then I have to re-use code in both, whereas with the .live() example, I am able to reference both selectors and the code will be executed on a click event for either selector. Also, I am using .live() because the click handler needs to apply to new elements added/created after the DOM is loaded. I know the .on() examples below will work for existing and new elements, but I must separate them because I can't figure out how to write the code where it will apply to both selectors while using the .on() syntax.

```
// Generic Example - Click handler for elements with an IDs beginning with "generic1_id_"
$(document).on('click', '[id^=generic1_id_]', function(){

}
```

AND

```
// Generic Example - Click handler for elements with an IDs beginning with "generic2_id_"
$(document).on('click', '[id^=generic2_id_]', function(){

}
```

I have tried this but it is not correct because the '[id^=generic2_id_]' will be interpreted as data not as a 2nd selector.

```
 // Won't work
 $(document).on('click', '[id^=generic1_id_]', '[id^=generic2_id_]', function(){
```

There is surprisingly little I can find in searches to find anything beyond simple examples of converting .live() to .on(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=generic1_id_],[id^=generic2_id_]', function(){ 
//your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct conversion would be:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=generic2_id_] [id^=generic1_id_]', function(){
```

because with your original, you used a comma between two different selectors, specifying both a *selector* and a *context*. .live always bound to the document, then it used the selector and context to filter the events that reach the document to only ones that both match the selector and are descendants of an element that matches the context.

<strike>It sounds though as if your original code doesn't actually do what you think it does.</strike>

```
$('[id^=generic1_id_]', '[id^=generic2_id_]').live('click', function(){
```

Your original code will bind a click event to all elements that match `[id^=generic1_id_]` and filter the events to only events that are raised by elements that match `[id^=generic2_id_]`

Comment: The new code also will not apply to newly created elements that match either `[id^=generic1_id_]` or `[id^=generic2_id_]`; for that, the selector (following the `'$'`) has to be a container that contains those elements.

Comment: It will for `[id^=generic1_id_]` elements but not `[id^=generic2_id_]` elements, just like the original code.

Comment: Hmm... actually.. it appears as though the original worked for both cases. I always thought it took the context into account, but it seems to always bind to the document regardless of the context (though it does take the context into account, change it to #foo and it stops working). http://jsfiddle.net/RB94h/

Comment: Hmm indeed. It was simpler when `live()` was the only choice, or even `delegate()` instead of `live()`. Just to cover all the bases, instead of `$(document).on()`, $(`some-selector`).on() would work, if `some-selector` contains the elements to be matched

Comment: Thanks Kevin B for the response. Your answer was very close but it needed the two selectors separated with a comma: $(document).on('click', '[id^=generic1_id_],[id^=generic2_id_]', function(){

Comment: My problem with that is that's not what your original code did.